# Prevent the rm_stopwords function creating a list

Tags: r, qdap

I used the `rm_stopwords` function from the `qdap` package to remove the stopwords and the punctuation from a text column in my data frame.

```
library(qdap)
library(dplyr)
library(tm)

glimpse(dat_full)
Observations: 500
Variables: 9
$ reviewerID     <chr> "ABF0ARHORHUUC", "AH4KMS2YC6TXA", "A2IXK5LB...
$ asin           <chr> "B00BE6C9S0", "B009X78DKU", "B0077PM3KG", "...
$ reviewerName   <chr> "stuartm \"stuartm\"", "HottMess", "G. Farn...
$ helpful        <list> [<1, 2>, <0, 0>, <0, 0>, <0, 0>, <0, 0>, <...
$ reviewText     <chr> "I've used the Mophie juice pack for my iPh...
$ overall        <dbl> 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3...
$ summary        <chr> "Case issues limit utility of this device",...
$ unixReviewTime <int> 1375142400, 1355356800, 1383350400, 1367193...
$ reviewTime     <chr> "07 30, 2013", "12 13, 2012", "11 2, 2013",...

full_dat$reviewText = rm_stopwords(full_dat$reviewText, 
tm::stopwords("english"), strip = TRUE)
```

The function returns a list of the reviewText column.

```
glimpse(full_dat)
Observations: 500
Variables: 9
$ reviewerID     <chr> "ABF0ARHORHUUC", "AH4KMS2YC6TXA", "A2IXK5LB...
$ asin           <chr> "B00BE6C9S0", "B009X78DKU", "B0077PM3KG", "...
$ reviewerName   <chr> "stuartm \"stuartm\"", "HottMess", "G. Farn...
$ helpful        <list> [<1, 2>, <0, 0>, <0, 0>, <0, 0>, <0, 0>, <...
$ reviewText     <list> [<"used", "mophie", "juice", "pack", "ipho...
$ overall        <dbl> 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3...
$ summary        <chr> "Case issues limit utility of this device",...
$ unixReviewTime <int> 1375142400, 1355356800, 1383350400, 1367193...
$ reviewTime     <chr> "07 30, 2013", "12 13, 2012", "11 2, 2013",...
```

Any Idea on how to prevent it (i.e keep the original format) or to unlist/unnest the column and return the original format?

The result should be like in the original data frame but without the stopwords and the punctuation.

Here is a small dput:

```
structure(list(reviewerID = "A3LWYDTO7928SH", asin = "B00B0FT2T4", 
    reviewerName = "D. Lang", helpful = list(c(0L, 0L)), reviewText = "When I first put your glass protector on my phone I was blown away!  (I knew how &#34;degrading&#34; the soft plastic covers were - ruining my experience, so I chose not to have a protector on my screen.)  Then I saw your website and I wondered if it was as good as spoken about.  The answer is YES.  The application was flawless even after I pulled the glass back off because I had not put it on absolutely perfectly.  It repositioned with ease and you could not find a bubble if you had a microscope!  Fascinating to see the viscous material on the back spread out on its own!  Application could not be easier and the quality of the product seems like it came from NASA.", 
    overall = 5, summary = "It is as perfect as a product can get - Really!", 
    unixReviewTime = 1396569600L, reviewTime = "04 4, 2014"), row.names = 145945L, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this in the dplyr pipeline. Using a combination of paste and unlist to get the result.

```
full_dat <- dat_full %>% 
  mutate(reviewText = map_chr(reviewText, 
                          function(x) paste0(unlist(qdap::rm_stopwords(x, 
                                                                       tm::stopwords("english"), 
                                                                       strip = TRUE)), 
                                             collapse = " ") 
                          )
         )
```

Comment: Thanks, but this code returns a reviewText which is the same in every row ("bad quite cheap expect extreme quality helps protects...")

Comment: Thanks, but this code returns a list.                                  
full_dat$reviewText[1]                                
[[1]]
[1] "love things"'